# Connect to Raspberry Pi 3 without ethernet and keyboard

Tags: pi-3, wifi, ubuntu, connection

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 without any monitor, keyboard or even LAN cable.

I only have a laptop with Ubuntu. Can I connect to Raspberry Pi 3 via wifi+SSH without ethernet?

I do not know the IP of Raspberry Pi. Even I do not know the wifi name of it.

Comment: Is your RP3 connected to any Wifi, where you have access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have *no* connection, it's going to be impossible. You need to get some sort of connection.

If the RPi is connected to an existing wifi network and you just want to find it, try:

`ssh raspberrypi.local`

This will only work if you know the hostname is still "raspberrypi". Otherwise, you can try to locate it with a portscan for port 22, although this may be a bad idea on a corporate network.

There are other possibilities, but any of these will require obtaining some sort of connection, either a cable of some sort, or a wifi configuration:

1. A [USB-TTL serial cable](https://www.adafruit.com/product/954) would allow you to connect via serial over the GPIO pins. You'd use some sort of serial communications program (e.g. `screen` on linux) to connect.
2. An Ethernet cable would allow you to directly connect the RPi to the laptop. Of course, the laptop has to have an Ethernet port. Both the laptop and RPi should be assigned IP address ranges in the LAN Local (169.254.x.x) range after approximately a minute. You should then be able to connect from your linux laptop with `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local`.
3. If the existing card is a recent raspbian version, create your own wireless network, perhaps using `hostapd` on your linux laptop. Configure the RPi by removing the card, mounting it on your linux laptop and configuring it to connect to your newly-create wifi network by creating a `wpa_supplicant.conf` file on the `boot` (VFAT) partition.

Be sure the RPi has `ssh` enabled. On recent raspbian versions, this is done by creating a file names `ssh` (no extension, can be empty) on the `boot` (VFAT) partition of the microSD card used to boot the RPi.

Getting connected is only part of the battle. Do you have a login account on the RPi? You could always create a new bootable microSD card.

Comment: Best way is download raspbian and install on SD card. Add the wpa_suppllicant adn ssh file. Then plug into pi (needs dongle if RPi2). Goto routers homepage, log into router and find your RPis ip address. SSH into pi : root@(ip here).

Comment: I believe the OP wants to log into the existing, running configuration. Based on OP not knowing the IP address and password, I'm assuming no control of the router. OP needs to clarify. Also, raspbian won't allow root login by default.

Comment: Oh sorry, I did pi@(ip) not root@(ip) sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As of the introduction of the current Raspbian Stretch O/S, you place a dummy file titled'SSH' in the boot directory when you load the O/S onto an SD card.

This will let you automatically connect using ssh and wifi. You can run 'headless' this way. Run raspi-config once a connection is established.